# HTML Mail template not loading correctly in outlook

Tags: javascript, html

Hello all I am having my email template as follows which is loading the styles correctly when loading in browser

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        /* -------------------------------------
            GLOBAL RESETS
        ------------------------------------- */
        img {
            border: none;
            -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
            max-width: 100%;
        }

        body {
            background-color: #f6f6f6;
            font-family: sans-serif;
            -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
            font-size: 14px;
            line-height: 1.4;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
            -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
        }

        table {
            border-collapse: separate;
            mso-table-lspace: 0pt;
            mso-table-rspace: 0pt;
            width: 100%;
        }

            table td {
                font-family: sans-serif;
                font-size: 14px;
                vertical-align: top;
            }
        /* -------------------------------------
            BODY & CONTAINER
        ------------------------------------- */
        .body {
            background-color: #f6f6f6;
            width: 100%;
        }
        /* Set a max-width, and make it display as block so it will automatically stretch to that width, but will also shrink down on a phone or something */
        .container {
            display: block;
            Margin: 0 auto !important;
            /* makes it centered */
            max-width: 580px;
            padding: 10px;
            width: 580px;
        }
        /* This should also be a block element, so that it will fill 100% of the .container */
        .content {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            display: block;
            Margin: 0 auto;
            max-width: 580px;
            padding: 10px;
        }
        /* -------------------------------------
            HEADER, FOOTER, MAIN
        ------------------------------------- */
        .main {
            background: #ffffff;
            border-radius: 3px;
            width: 100%;
        }

        .wrapper {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            padding: 20px;
        }

        .content-block {
            padding-bottom: 10px;
            padding-top: 10px;
        }

        .footer {
            clear: both;
            Margin-top: 10px;
            text-align: center;
            width: 100%;
        }

            .footer td,
            .footer p,
            .footer span,
            .footer a {
                color: #999999;
                font-size: 12px;
                text-align: center;
            }
        /* -------------------------------------
            TYPOGRAPHY
        ------------------------------------- */
        h1,
        h2,
        h3,
        h4 {
            color: #000000;
            font-family: sans-serif;
            font-weight: 400;
            line-height: 1.4;
            margin: 0;
            Margin-bottom: 30px;
        }

        h1 {
            font-size: 35px;
            font-weight: 300;
            text-align: center;
            text-transform: capitalize;
        }

        p,
        ul,
        ol {
            font-family: sans-serif;
            font-size: 14px;
            font-weight: normal;
            margin: 0;
            Margin-bottom: 15px;
        }

            p li,
            ul li,
            ol li {
                list-style-position: inside;
                margin-left: 5px;
            }

        a {
            color: #3498db;
            text-decoration: underline;
        }
        /* -------------------------------------
            BUTTONS
        ------------------------------------- */
        .btn {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            width: 100%;
        }

            .btn > tbody > tr > td {
                padding-bottom: 15px;
            }

            .btn table {
                width: auto;
            }

                .btn table td {
                    background-color: #ffffff;
                    border-radius: 5px;
                    text-align: center;
                }

            .btn a {
                background-color: #ffffff;
                border: solid 1px #3498db;
                border-radius: 5px;
                box-sizing: border-box;
                color: #3498db;
                cursor: pointer;
                display: inline-block;
                font-size: 14px;
                font-weight: bold;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 12px 25px;
                text-decoration: none;
                text-transform: capitalize;
            }

        .btn-primary table td {
            background-color: #3498db;
        }

        .btn-primary a {
            background-color: #3498db;
            border-color: #3498db;
            color: #ffffff;
        }
        /* -------------------------------------
            OTHER STYLES THAT MIGHT BE USEFUL
        ------------------------------------- */
        .last {
            margin-bottom: 0;
        }

        .first {
            margin-top: 0;
        }

        .align-center {
            text-align: center;
        }

        .align-right {
            text-align: right;
        }

        .align-left {
            text-align: left;
        }

        .clear {
            clear: both;
        }

        .mt0 {
            margin-top: 0;
        }

        .mb0 {
            margin-bottom: 0;
        }

        .preheader {
            color: transparent;
            display: none;
            height: 0;
            max-height: 0;
            max-width: 0;
            opacity: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
            mso-hide: all;
            visibility: hidden;
            width: 0;
        }

        .powered-by a {
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        hr {
            border: 0;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #f6f6f6;
            Margin: 20px 0;
        }
        /* -------------------------------------
            RESPONSIVE AND MOBILE FRIENDLY STYLES
        ------------------------------------- */
        @media only screen and (max-width: 620px) {
            table[class=body] h1 {
                font-size: 28px !important;
                margin-bottom: 10px !important;
            }

            table[class=body] p,
            table[class=body] ul,
            table[class=body] ol,
            table[class=body] td,
            table[class=body] span,
            table[class=body] a {
                font-size: 16px !important;
            }

            table[class=body] .wrapper,
            table[class=body] .article {
                padding: 10px !important;
            }

            table[class=body] .content {
                padding: 0 !important;
            }

            table[class=body] .container {
                padding: 0 !important;
                width: 100% !important;
            }

            table[class=body] .main {
                border-left-width: 0 !important;
                border-radius: 0 !important;
                border-right-width: 0 !important;
            }

            table[class=body] .btn table {
                width: 100% !important;
            }

            table[class=body] .btn a {
                width: 100% !important;
            }

            table[class=body] .img-responsive {
                height: auto !important;
                max-width: 100% !important;
                width: auto !important;
            }
        }
        /* -------------------------------------
            PRESERVE THESE STYLES IN THE HEAD
        ------------------------------------- */
        @media all {
            .ExternalClass {
                width: 100%;
            }

                .ExternalClass,
                .ExternalClass p,
                .ExternalClass span,
                .ExternalClass font,
                .ExternalClass td,
                .ExternalClass div {
                    line-height: 100%;
                }

            .apple-link a {
                color: inherit !important;
                font-family: inherit !important;
                font-size: inherit !important;
                font-weight: inherit !important;
                line-height: inherit !important;
                text-decoration: none !important;
            }

            .btn-primary table td:hover {
                background-color: #34495e !important;
            }

            .btn-primary a:hover {
                background-color: #34495e !important;
                border-color: #34495e !important;
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body class="">
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="body">
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="container">
                <div class="content">

                    <!-- START CENTERED WHITE CONTAINER -->
                    <span class="preheader"><img src="https://www.google.co.in/search?q=logo&tbm=isch&source=iu&ictx=1&fir=EXasrO6-zoqc7M%253A%252C1FqkMM1hJtCa2M%252C_&usg=__AtYHsyCqJARa0Fvxa5Q0qZdHW7M%3D&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjT6PLExIrcAhWSN30KHVmBAg8Q9QEIKjAA#imgrc=EXasrO6-zoqc7M:" /></span>
                    <table class="main" border="0">

                        <!-- START MAIN CONTENT AREA -->
                        <tr>
                            <td class="wrapper">
                                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><span style="color:grey;">Company</span></td>
                                        <td><img src="[imgPath]" /></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <br /><p>Hi [username],</p>
                                            <p>You have been assigned to an active task.</p>
                                            <p style="text-align:center; line-height:3;height:40px;background: rgba(171, 205, 239, 0.3)">Task assigned by [assignee] on [assigneddate]</p>
                                            <hr />
                                            <p><b>Task Name : [Task]</b></p>
                                            <p><b>Project : [Project]</b></p>
                                            <p><b>Scheduled from : [startdate] to [enddate]</b></p>
                                            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="btn btn-primary">
                                                <tbody>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td align="left">
                                                            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                                                <tbody>
                                                                    <tr>
                                                                        <td> <a href="http://192.168.1.30:8082" target="_blank">Login</a> </td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                </tbody>
                                                            </table>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </tbody>
                                            </table>
                                            <br />
                                            <p>Thank you,</p>
                                            <p><b>Admin</b></p>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <!-- END MAIN CONTENT AREA -->
                    </table>

                    <!-- START FOOTER -->
                    <div class="footer">
                        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                            <tr>
                                <td class="content-block">
                                    <span class="apple-link">
                                        © [currentyear] Company, Inc. All Right Reserved
                                    </span>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <!-- END FOOTER -->
                    <!-- END CENTERED WHITE CONTAINER -->
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

I would like to display the content with the style as it is getting displayed, but I couldn't can some one tell me what changes I need to do

In browser

[image]

In outlook
[image: outlook]

Comment: Have you tried emailing it? If so, what is the output?

Comment: How can we help you if we cannot see the incorrect output. It would also help if you tell us explicitly what is wrong with the resulting rendering

Comment: **OP**, post a screenshot of what is the problem within _Outlook_ and explain what needs to be fixed.

Comment: Usually Outlook does not render style written outside, inline styling will help in that case.

Comment: updated the images

Answer (score 0):

Emailing html is usually a pain in the ***ss.

It's much like a test & error practice, cause lots of emails renderes do it's own rules, but anyway.

What you need to do first, and very important, is to ***inline your styles***.

You can try some online tools like https://templates.mailchimp.com/resources/inline-css/

This is the result of your code with inlining css:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        /* -------------------------------------
            GLOBAL RESETS
        ------------------------------------- */
        img {
            border: none;
            -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
            max-width: 100%;
        }

        body {
            background-color: #f6f6f6;
            font-family: sans-serif;
            -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
            font-size: 14px;
            line-height: 1.4;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
            -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
        }

        table {
            border-collapse: separate;
            mso-table-lspace: 0pt;
            mso-table-rspace: 0pt;
            width: 100%;
        }

            table td {
                font-family: sans-serif;
                font-size: 14px;
                vertical-align: top;
            }
        /* -------------------------------------
            BODY & CONTAINER
        ------------------------------------- */
        .body {
            background-color: #f6f6f6;
            width: 100%;
        }
        /* Set a max-width, and make it display as block so it will automatically stretch to that width, but will also shrink down on a phone or something */
        .container {
            display: block;
            Margin: 0 auto !important;
            /* makes it centered */
            max-width: 580px;
            padding: 10px;
            width: 580px;
        }
        /* This should also be a block element, so that it will fill 100% of the .container */
        .content {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            display: block;
            Margin: 0 auto;
            max-width: 580px;
            padding: 10px;
        }
        /* -------------------------------------
            HEADER, FOOTER, MAIN
        ------------------------------------- */
        .main {
            background: #ffffff;
            border-radius: 3px;
            width: 100%;
        }

        .wrapper {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            padding: 20px;
        }

        .content-block {
            padding-bottom: 10px;
            padding-top: 10px;
        }

        .footer {
            clear: both;
            Margin-top: 10px;
            text-align: center;
            width: 100%;
        }

            .footer td,
            .footer p,
            .footer span,
            .footer a {
                color: #999999;
                font-size: 12px;
                text-align: center;
            }
        /* -------------------------------------
            TYPOGRAPHY
        ------------------------------------- */
        h1,
        h2,
        h3,
        h4 {
            color: #000000;
            font-family: sans-serif;
            font-weight: 400;
            line-height: 1.4;
            margin: 0;
            Margin-bottom: 30px;
        }

        h1 {
            font-size: 35px;
            font-weight: 300;
            text-align: center;
            text-transform: capitalize;
        }

        p,
        ul,
        ol {
            font-family: sans-serif;
            font-size: 14px;
            font-weight: normal;
            margin: 0;
            Margin-bottom: 15px;
        }

            p li,
            ul li,
            ol li {
                list-style-position: inside;
                margin-left: 5px;
            }

        a {
            color: #3498db;
            text-decoration: underline;
        }
        /* -------------------------------------
            BUTTONS
        ------------------------------------- */
        .btn {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            width: 100%;
        }

            .btn > tbody > tr > td {
                padding-bottom: 15px;
            }

            .btn table {
                width: auto;
            }

                .btn table td {
                    background-color: #ffffff;
                    border-radius: 5px;
                    text-align: center;
                }

            .btn a {
                background-color: #ffffff;
                border: solid 1px #3498db;
                border-radius: 5px;
                box-sizing: border-box;
                color: #3498db;
                cursor: pointer;
                display: inline-block;
                font-size: 14px;
                font-weight: bold;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 12px 25px;
                text-decoration: none;
                text-transform: capitalize;
            }

        .btn-primary table td {
            background-color: #3498db;
        }

        .btn-primary a {
            background-color: #3498db;
            border-color: #3498db;
            color: #ffffff;
        }
        /* -------------------------------------
            OTHER STYLES THAT MIGHT BE USEFUL
        ------------------------------------- */
        .last {
            margin-bottom: 0;
        }

        .first {
            margin-top: 0;
        }

        .align-center {
            text-align: center;
        }

        .align-right {
            text-align: right;
        }

        .align-left {
            text-align: left;
        }

        .clear {
            clear: both;
        }

        .mt0 {
            margin-top: 0;
        }

        .mb0 {
            margin-bottom: 0;
        }

        .preheader {
            color: transparent;
            display: none;
            height: 0;
            max-height: 0;
            max-width: 0;
            opacity: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
            mso-hide: all;
            visibility: hidden;
            width: 0;
        }

        .powered-by a {
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        hr {
            border: 0;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #f6f6f6;
            Margin: 20px 0;
        }
        /* -------------------------------------
            RESPONSIVE AND MOBILE FRIENDLY STYLES
        ------------------------------------- */
        @media only screen and (max-width: 620px) {
            table[class=body] h1 {
                font-size: 28px !important;
                margin-bottom: 10px !important;
            }

            table[class=body] p,
            table[class=body] ul,
            table[class=body] ol,
            table[class=body] td,
            table[class=body] span,
            table[class=body] a {
                font-size: 16px !important;
            }

            table[class=body] .wrapper,
            table[class=body] .article {
                padding: 10px !important;
            }

            table[class=body] .content {
                padding: 0 !important;
            }

            table[class=body] .container {
                padding: 0 !important;
                width: 100% !important;
            }

            table[class=body] .main {
                border-left-width: 0 !important;
                border-radius: 0 !important;
                border-right-width: 0 !important;
            }

            table[class=body] .btn table {
                width: 100% !important;
            }

            table[class=body] .btn a {
                width: 100% !important;
            }

            table[class=body] .img-responsive {
                height: auto !important;
                max-width: 100% !important;
                width: auto !important;
            }
        }
        /* -------------------------------------
            PRESERVE THESE STYLES IN THE HEAD
        ------------------------------------- */
        @media all {
            .ExternalClass {
                width: 100%;
            }

                .ExternalClass,
                .ExternalClass p,
                .ExternalClass span,
                .ExternalClass font,
                .ExternalClass td,
                .ExternalClass div {
                    line-height: 100%;
                }

            .apple-link a {
                color: inherit !important;
                font-family: inherit !important;
                font-size: inherit !important;
                font-weight: inherit !important;
                line-height: inherit !important;
                text-decoration: none !important;
            }

            .btn-primary table td:hover {
                background-color: #34495e !important;
            }

            .btn-primary a:hover {
                background-color: #34495e !important;
                border-color: #34495e !important;
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body class="" style="background-color: #f6f6f6;font-family: sans-serif;-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;font-size: 14px;line-height: 1.4;margin: 0;padding: 0;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;">
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="body" style="border-collapse: separate;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;width: 100%;background-color: #f6f6f6;">
        <tr>
            <td style="font-family: sans-serif;font-size: 14px;vertical-align: top;">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="container" style="font-family: sans-serif;font-size: 14px;vertical-align: top;display: block;max-width: 580px;padding: 10px;width: 580px;margin: 0 auto !important;">
                <div class="content" style="box-sizing: border-box;display: block;margin: 0 auto;max-width: 580px;padding: 10px;">

                    <!-- START CENTERED WHITE CONTAINER -->
                    <span class="preheader" style="color: transparent;display: none;height: 0;max-height: 0;max-width: 0;opacity: 0;overflow: hidden;mso-hide: all;visibility: hidden;width: 0;"><img src="https://www.google.co.in/search?q=logo&tbm=isch&source=iu&ictx=1&fir=EXasrO6-zoqc7M%253A%252C1FqkMM1hJtCa2M%252C_&usg=__AtYHsyCqJARa0Fvxa5Q0qZdHW7M%3D&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjT6PLExIrcAhWSN30KHVmBAg8Q9QEIKjAA#imgrc=EXasrO6-zoqc7M:" style="border: none;-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;max-width: 100%;"></span>
                    <table class="main" border="0" style="border-collapse: separate;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;width: 100%;background: #ffffff;border-radius: 3px;">

                        <!-- START MAIN CONTENT AREA -->
                        <tr>
                            <td class="wrapper" style="font-family: sans-serif;font-size: 14px;vertical-align: top;box-sizing: border-box;padding: 20px;">
                                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: separate;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;width: 100%;">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="font-family: sans-serif;font-size: 14px;vertical-align: top;"><span style="color:grey;">Company</span></td>
                                        <td style="font-family: sans-serif;font-size: 14px;vertical-align: top;"><img src="[imgPath]" style="border: none;-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;max-width: 100%;"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="font-family: sans-serif;font-size: 14px;vertical-align: top;">
                                            <br><p style="font-family: sans-serif;font-size: 14px;font-weight: normal;margin: 0;margin-bottom: 15px;">Hi [username],</p>
                                            <p style="font-family: sans-serif;font-size: 14px;font-weight: normal;margin: 0;margin-bottom: 15px;">You have been assigned to an active task.</p>
                                            <p style="text-align: center;line-height: 3;height: 40px;background: rgba(171, 205, 239, 0.3);font-family: sans-serif;font-size: 14px;font-weight: normal;margin: 0;margin-bottom: 15px;">Task assigned by [assignee] on [assigneddate]</p>
                                            <hr style="border: 0;border-bottom: 1px solid #f6f6f6;margin: 20px 0;">
                                            <p style="font-family: sans-serif;font-size: 14px;font-weight: normal;margin: 0;margin-bottom: 15px;"><b>Task Name : [Task]</b></p>
                                            <p style="font-family: sans-serif;font-size: 14px;font-weight: normal;margin: 0;margin-bottom: 15px;"><b>Project : [Project]</b></p>
                                            <p style="font-family: sans-serif;font-size: 14px;font-weight: normal;margin: 0;margin-bottom: 15px;"><b>Scheduled from : [startdate] to [enddate]</b></p>
                                            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="btn btn-primary" style="border-collapse: separate;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;width: 100%;box-sizing: border-box;">
                                                <tbody>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td align="left" style="font-family: sans-serif;font-size: 14px;vertical-align: top;padding-bottom: 15px;">
                                                            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: separate;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;width: auto;">
                                                                <tbody>
                                                                    <tr>
                                                                        <td style="font-family: sans-serif;font-size: 14px;vertical-align: top;background-color: #3498db;border-radius: 5px;text-align: center;"> <a href="http://192.168.1.30:8082" target="_blank" style="color: #ffffff;text-decoration: none;background-color: #3498db;border: solid 1px #3498db;border-radius: 5px;box-sizing: border-box;cursor: pointer;display: inline-block;font-size: 14px;font-weight: bold;margin: 0;padding: 12px 25px;text-transform: capitalize;border-color: #3498db;">Login</a> </td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                </tbody>
                                                            </table>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </tbody>
                                            </table>
                                            <br>
                                            <p style="font-family: sans-serif;font-size: 14px;font-weight: normal;margin: 0;margin-bottom: 15px;">Thank you,</p>
                                            <p style="font-family: sans-serif;font-size: 14px;font-weight: normal;margin: 0;margin-bottom: 15px;"><b>Admin</b></p>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <!-- END MAIN CONTENT AREA -->
                    </table>

                    <!-- START FOOTER -->
                    <div class="footer" style="clear: both;margin-top: 10px;text-align: center;width: 100%;">
                        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: separate;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;width: 100%;">
                            <tr>
                                <td class="content-block" style="font-family: sans-serif;font-size: 12px;vertical-align: top;padding-bottom: 10px;padding-top: 10px;color: #999999;text-align: center;">
                                    <span class="apple-link" style="color: #999999;font-size: 12px;text-align: center;">
                                        © [currentyear] Company, Inc. All Right Reserved
                                    </span>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <!-- END FOOTER -->
                    <!-- END CENTERED WHITE CONTAINER -->
                </div>
            </td>
            <td style="font-family: sans-serif;font-size: 14px;vertical-align: top;">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks but this is how I am getting https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0HJi.png

Comment: Button is a displaying a bit large and I am not seeing style on Task assgined